# How do I set default view preferences in Adobe Acrobat?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

In Acrobat Pro, I try to set preferences (open in "page-width" view and use "one-page continuous) but it only makes changes for the document I have open, not as default for every time I open.

Answer (score 9):

The "Default Page Layout" option never worked for me, but I've found another option in the Preferences that seems to work:

Open **Preferences**. In the **Accessibility** category, under "Override Page Display" check the **Always use Page Layout Style** and select the preferred option. This works as a default setting for opened pdf documents.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that to change the default for the "Single Page Continuous" (or one-page continuous)

1. In the **Preferences** dialog box under **Categories**, select **Page Display**.
2. Open the Page Layout menu and choose **Single Page Continuous**

What are you trying to do, create PDFs? Edit PDFs...?

***Note:*** The PDF opens with the page layout specified in Preferences unless a different page layout is specified in Document Properties (File > Properties > Initial View). The Document Properties setting overrides the Preferences setting. If using Document Properties, be sure to save and close the document for the change to take effect. Acrobat users can change the initial view, unless security settings prevent changes. Reader users cannot change the initial view.

BTW, welcome to [SuperUser](http://SuperUser.com)  When you get a chance, read the [FAQs](https://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: Too bad there is no way to ignore *Initial View* for all documents.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for **Adobe Acrobat Pro DC** only.

---

Head to **File** > **Document Properties** (Ctrl-D)

Click on the **Initial view** tab, there, the first few fields are for setting the default view for that document. These preferences may be ignored depending on the application used to view the document, but should work in Adobe products (Acrobat and Reader).

Once set, accept the changes and save the document.

Answer (score 0):

with PDF open, go to "Edit" on top left, then to "Preference", in "Preference" go to "Page Display", under "Default", go to "Layout and Zoom", go to "Zoom" and select size you want on page. Worked for me in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to uncheck 'Restore last view settings when reopening documents' in Edit > Preferences > Documents > Open Settings.

Otherwise every time you open a document, it will appear with the last view settings you used for it. Which might not be the settings you want!

Answer (score -1):

If you set it in the document properties that is for that document. However, the general properties for your use is under Edit>Preferences>Page Display

Comment: That has already been mentioned in an answer a few years ago.  What's the point of repeating it now?